# Generic method cannot be accessed

Tags: c#, generics

I have currently been learning and researching Generic's inside C# but am struggling with actually using the method once created.

I have tried:

```
public class myTestClass
{
    class example
    {
        public static DataTable LINQtoDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            PropertyInfo[] objectProps = null; // Reflection

            if (data == null) return null;
            foreach (T record in data)
            {
                if (objectProps == null) objectProps = ((Type)data.GetType()).GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in objectProps)
                {
                    Type columnType = pi.PropertyType;
                    if ((columnType.IsGenericType) && (columnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))) columnType = columnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, columnType));
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }

    }

    example ex { get; set; }

    public myTestClass()
    {
        this.ex = new example();
    }
}
```

But when I do (In a C# Form):

```
// Namespace area
myTestClass test;
// Main Method
test = new myTestClass();
```

`test.LINQtoDataTable()` doesn't come up or exist. Can anyone please help me out? I am confused to why this won't appear since I public'd the method and instanced the class it is inside :(

Greatly appreciated & thanks in advance.

Comment: `LINQtoDataTable` is a static method inside a private nested class, so `test.LINQtoDataTable` won't work.

Comment: You need it as a static class as well (where the data parameter needs to be set to this), you can research extension methods a bit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create extension method, and for extension method there are some pre-requisites for the method to have, it should be static and in a static class, the one you are missing is `this` keyword and your class is not **static** in start of it:

```
public static DataTable LINQtoDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     PropertyInfo[] objectProps = null; // Reflection

     if (data == null) return null;
     foreach (T record in data)
     {
        if (objectProps == null) objectProps = ((Type)data.GetType()).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in objectProps)
        {
             Type columnType = pi.PropertyType;
             if ((columnType.IsGenericType) && (columnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))) columnType = columnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, columnType));
        }
     }
     return dt;
}
```

and you will still now see it in intellisense, because you are creating extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` while you are trying to call it on just `T`.

For able to call it, you have to create a `List<T>` :

```
List<myTestClass> listTestClass = new List<myTestClass>();
listTestClass.Add(new myTestClass());
listTestClass.LINQtoDataTable();
```

I once wrote a blog post on extension methods topic, you may want to read about extension method with a simple example[here](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2015/04/extension-methods-feature-in-c-with.html)

Comment: Appreciated, I made these changes to the method

Answer (score 3):

An [extension-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exists in a static public class whilst your current code has only a static method within a private class. So you need this:

```
 public static class MyTestClass {
     public static DataTable LINQtoDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data) { ... }
 }
```

Furthermore you need the `this`-keyword on the param you want to be that extension-method be bound to.

Last an extension-method can´t stay in a nested class, which you apparently don´t really need at all. Delete the nested class and make `MyTestClass` (also consider the [naming-conventions for classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xhs4564%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) publc and static and put the method there. Thus you won´t need any instance of this class. Simpy call `myEnumerable.LINQtoDataTable()`.

Comment: I seem to not be able to create an instance for a static class now :/

Comment: @KyleE4K No you should extract this to an "Extension" class, it doesn't need to be included in your example class if this is the one you wish to use to initiate the object. The important part would be that the class where the extension method is defined is static and that your method's first parameter contains the this keyword (in case you want extension methods)

Comment: Oh! I understand now, that makes more sense now. Sorry about the confusion, I've never used generics because I have come from PHP and of course, you don't declare data types anyway in that. Appreciated this! - Ill mark this when I can, its all working now!

Comment: Extensions methods are for extending the functionality of classes without editing the existing code, as BCL are in framework, we cannot change code of them normally

Comment: This can get so confusing when trying to learn Entity, LINQ, Generics and Classes at once :/ Appreciated though. I'll also check your blog on it @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ

Answer (score 2):

becuse the `LINQtoDataTable` metode it static, is not need an `example` instance. which locat in  the `ex` propery, and accessible via  its name.

```
myTestClass.example.LINQtoDataTable(...)
```